# I am getting a required error using graphql tools

Tags: javascript, graphql, nodes, graphql-js

I am building a gql server application using apollo server.

When I try to load my `.graphql` files using `import { loadFilesSync } from '@graphql-tools/load-files'`, this works very well, but when I load my resolver files, i get an error

```
node:internal/errors:464
    ErrorCaptureStackTrace(err);
    ^

Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module /userpath/index.js from /userpath/server-gql/noop.js not supported.
Instead change the require of index.js in /userpath/server-gql/noop.js to a dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS modules.
    at Object.newLoader [as .js] (/userpath/server-gql/node_modules/pirates/lib/index.js:141:7)
    at file:///userpath/server-gql/node_modules/@graphql-tools/load-files/esm/index.js:104:33
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at loadFilesSync (file:///userpath/server-gql/node_modules/@graphql-tools/load-files/esm/index.js:95:10)
    at file:///userpath/server-gql/schema.js:20:24
    at async Promise.all (index 0) {
  code: 'ERR_REQUIRE_ESM'
}
```

I am using `"type": "module"` in my `package.json`.

Here's my code snippet for where i get the error

```
import path from 'path'
import { fileURLToPath } from 'url'

import { loadFilesSync } from '@graphql-tools/load-files'
import { mergeTypeDefs, mergeResolvers } from '@graphql-tools/merge'


const __filename = fileURLToPath(import.meta.url)
const __dirname = path.dirname(__filename)

const typesArray = loadFilesSync(path.join(__dirname, '.'), {
  recursive: true,
  extensions: ['graphql'],
})



const resolversArray = loadFilesSync(path.join(__dirname, './graphql/**/*.resolvers.js'), {
  recursive: true,
  extensions: ['js'],
})



const newResolversArray = resolversArray.slice(1)



export const typeDefs = mergeTypeDefs(typesArray)
export const resolvers = mergeResolvers(newResolversArray)
```

I think the error occurs in the resolvers array.

Answer (score 2):

ESM(ECMAScript modules - import/export) loading logic is asynchronous, so it seems like you can't use loadFilesSync when using ESM.

The following code will technically work but won't be right because it will use `require` to load the modules.

```
const resolversArray = await loadFiles(resolversPath);
```

So I think a more correct version will be:

```
import { pathToFileURL } from 'url';

const resolversArray = await loadFiles(resolversPath, {
        requireMethod: async (path) => {
            console.debug('Using resolver at:', path);
            return await import(pathToFileURL(path));
        }
});
```

Now, apparently if you're using the `mjs` file extension for your modules, you will need to also specify a `useRequire` option to load the file using the `requireMethod` no matter the file's extension:

```
import { pathToFileURL } from 'url';

const resolversArray = await loadFiles(resolversPath, {
        useRequire: true,
        requireMethod: async (path) => {
            console.debug('Using resolver at:', path);
            return await import(pathToFileURL(path));
        }
});
```

+You'll need to specify the extension in either the path or the `extensions` option

[You can see the default extensions here](https://github.com/ardatan/graphql-tools/blob/master/packages/load-files/src/index.ts#L95-L96)

I just used the extension in the path, like so:

```
import path from 'path';
import { fileURLToPath } from 'url';

const __filename = fileURLToPath(import.meta.url);
const __dirname = path.dirname(__filename);

const resolversPath = path.join(
        __dirname, 'resolvers', '**', '*.resolvers.mjs'
);
```

So now every file(recursively) inside the resolvers folder that's inside the folder of the current file with the file extension of `resolvers.mjs` will be loaded.

Oh, on an unrelated note, you can use `mergeResolvers` from the `@graphql-tools/merge` package to merge needed resolvers gracefully(resolvers under Query for example).

Full example:

```
import { loadFiles } from '@graphql-tools/load-files';

import path from 'path';
import { fileURLToPath, pathToFileURL } from 'url';

const __filename = fileURLToPath(import.meta.url);
const __dirname = path.dirname(__filename);

async function getResolvers() {
    const resolversPath = path.join(
        __dirname, 'resolvers', '**', '*.resolvers.mjs'
    );
    const resolversArray = await loadFiles(resolversPath, {
        useRequire: true,
        requireMethod: async (path) => {
            console.debug('Using resolver at:', path);
            return await import(pathToFileURL(path));
        }
    });
    return mergeResolvers(resolversArray);
}

const resolvers = await getResolvers();
console.debug('GraphQL used resolvers:');
console.debug(resolvers);
```

Answer (score 1):

I was running into a very similar issue and found this workaround/solution worked for me: https://github.com/ardatan/graphql-tools/issues/1750#issuecomment-655828240

I had to modify that answer a bit to get it working in my codebase...below is what my own `resolverFiles` snippet now looks like (I'm not 100% sure what your import/naming conventions look like, or I'd try to apply this to your code snippet).

I have a mixed, nested directory `schema/` that contains resolver files of the format `SomethingResolvers.ts`. Each of these look like the following (I'm using codegen):

```
import { Resolvers } from "../../generated/graphql";

export const resolvers: Resolvers = { /* resolver implementations */ };
```

```
const resolverFiles = await loadFiles(
  path.join(__dirname, "**/*Resolvers.js"),
  {
    requireMethod: async (path) => {
      const module = await import(pathToFileURL(path).toString());

      return module["resolvers"];
    },
    recursive: true,
  }
);
```